# mvc 3 html attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have been playing around with MVC. I am currently stumped on with html helper methods. One thing i have noticed is that I cant really cant apply the ASP.NET Web Form logic into MVC. To explain further, in ASP.NET I could create a Label control and assign it some text data and then read the text data.

However, in MVC, I cant seem to do the same with @Html.LabelFor/@Html.Label, I have realised that once you do a POST from your form, the value from the Label is not bound back into my view model. However, if I use an EditorFor or TextBoxFor, I can get values bound to my viewmodel upon POST.

My question what html hlper method should I use to display text as readonly but yet be able to bind back to my viewmodel upon post ? I have tried TextBoxFor with its html attributes set to disabled and readonly but no luck.

Appreciate any pointers.
thanks

Comment: how are you trying to bind this attribute?

Comment: thanks for the replies. my binding in my markup is as: @html.Label(Model.Username). essentially on POST, I have an action method public View FormPost(MyViewModel vm). I simply extract the contents of the variable "vm" and stick it inside a service method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to bind the `readonly` attribute to the `TextBox` by passing in `htmlAttributes` as the 2nd parameter of the `TextBoxFor` method:

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty, new { @readonly = "readonly" }) %>
```

On MSDN: [InputExtensions.TextBoxFor Method (HtmlHelper, Expression>, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703538.aspx)

---

If you're trying to maintain the Label value you can use a combination of the `LabelFor` and `HiddenFor` methods.

I don't know why you would need to do this though, since you should be able to get the DisplayText attribute or the Property Name from the property.

```
<%=Html.LabelFor(m => m.SomeProperty) %>
<%=Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SomeProperty) %>
```

but this doesn't make a lot of sense since the usual syntax would be:

```
<%=Html.LabelFor(m => m.SomeProperty) %>
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty) %>
```

---

Note that if you use the `disabled` attribute the input will not be posted when the form is submitted

Comment: The reason I need to display certain data as readonly or in Label controls is simply due to the nature of how the form is manipulated. As I said earlier my Label needs to display the value of my property i.e. model.UserName which could contain "peterparker". What you have written about HiddenFor field is the simplest solution to my problem.

Comment: Also note that you can't use `Html.EditorFor()` method if you need to specify HTMLAttributes, you have to use something like `TextBoxFor()`, `DropDownListFor()`, etc. I didn't realize it until I took a closer look at my method calls that I was calling the wrong one to allow HtmlAttributes to be passed in.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour, only values form elements are added to your Model on POST so your label will be ignored. To get around this duplicate your label value in a hidden field

```
Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FieldName)
```

or

```
Html.Hidden("FieldName", model.FieldName)
```